# AWS CloudFormation: "Parameter [subnetIds] is invalid"

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline

I have a AWS CodePipeline to deploy a stack in CloudFormation using a YAML template as well as a template configuration JSON file.

**Relevant Template Snippet:**

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
...
Parameters:
  subnetIds:
    Type: List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>
...
```

**Relevant Configuration File Snippet:**

```
{
    "Parameters": {
      ...
      "subnetIds": [
        "subnet-a",
        "subnet-b",
        "subnet-c"
      ]
    },
    ...
}
```

For some reason the Deploy stage (CloudFormation) keeps failing with `Parameter [subnetIds] is invalid`, so my question is how do I pass a list of subnetIds to the template from the configuration file?

Comment: The template state the value of an entry in the array should be like this: AWS::EC2::Subnet::I'd (the :: are a delimiter) but you are provide only 1 string value

Comment: You might like to amend your question to be explicit that you are using AWS CodePipeline. I have inferred that from the format of the template you mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is explained [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html) in the docs about list data types, such as:

> `List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>`
>
> An array of subnet IDs, such as `subnet-123a351e, subnet-456b351e`.

That is to say, all `List` types in CloudFormation are also comma-separated strings.

Since you are using a CodePipeline [Template Configuration File](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/continuous-delivery-codepipeline-cfn-artifacts.html#w2ab1c13c15c15), you will have something like:

```json
{
  "Parameters": {
    "subnetIds": "subnet-a,subnet-b,subnet-c"
  }
}
```